# .NET And Shared DLLs

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, assemblies

I have 4 .Net Applications that use the same set of API DLLs. All these files sit on a flash drives we give to our staff. Is there any way to have a shared DLL location on the flash drive for all the shared DLLs so when we update, we don't have to duplicate the DLLs for each Application. I have Read about global assemblies but this will not always work if theres a new PC or they are at a client site.

I have read about disabling copy local but is that a relative path or absolute once you do that.

Example of Drive Structure
F:\ 
|
|-App1\
|-App2\
|-App3\
|-App4\
|-SharedDLLs\

Comment: You mean like producing new assemblies and having those new assemblies automagically appear on the flash drives of all the members of your staff? Because if this is the question, then the answer is simple: **no**. Maybe you should consider different medias to distribute your application. Things like network shares or web applications seem pretty common nowadays.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneakernet

Comment: Another route you could consider would be wrapping your DLLs in a web service and exposing your API that way.

Comment: @RandomITGuy: How does your app knows that your DLL is in F:\shared? How do you deal with references to something like this? Just have each app with full set of DLLs, if you don't use GAC. I think, this is one of those cases when you not need to "optimize". Your build process should create the useful output. And really, think about some sort of "secure download" mechanism instead of flash.

Answer (score 0):

to me having burned dlls in your projects is a complete nigtmare, I suggest you to try nuget and create a private feed for your custom dlls you just need to host a web service in a local server and everbody should configure the access to that dependencies.

it's quite easy take a look to this [tutorial](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds) it worth the effort!